# Adding a theme (one of three themes) when you switch, and a mode (dark or light) when you toggle, to a HTML element in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am going to generate from Markdowm to a single offline HTML page with inline styles and inline scripts. It has a selection list of three themes, using `:root` and a toggle of dark or light modes, with classes `.vscode-dark` and `.vscode-light`, based on VSCode's Markdowm Preview.

```html
<p> Choose one theme</p>
<select name="theme-select" id="theme-select">
  <option value="voxel-theme-empresas">empresas</option>
  <option value="voxel-theme-ion">ion</option>
  <option value="voxel-theme-iti">iti</option>
</select>

<button onclick="switchMode()">Toggle dark or light mode</button>

<script>
function switchMode() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("vscode-dark");
}
</script>
```

It should be like:

```html
<body class="voxel-theme-empresas vscode-light">

# Teste 2

Nostrud nostrud excepteur mollit anim. Sint proident officia anim eu pariatur laboris excepteur amet Lorem Lorem commodo consequat ullamco. Pariatur aute ut aliqua aliquip consectetur ea.

</body>

<body class="voxel-theme-empresas vscode-dark">

# Teste 2

Nostrud nostrud excepteur mollit anim. Sint proident officia anim eu pariatur laboris excepteur amet Lorem Lorem commodo consequat ullamco. Pariatur aute ut aliqua aliquip consectetur ea.

</body>

<body class="voxel-theme-iti vscode-light">

# Teste 2

Nostrud nostrud excepteur mollit anim. Sint proident officia anim eu pariatur laboris excepteur amet Lorem Lorem commodo consequat ullamco. Pariatur aute ut aliqua aliquip consectetur ea.

</body>

<body class="voxel-theme-iti vscode-dark">

# Teste 2

Nostrud nostrud excepteur mollit anim. Sint proident officia anim eu pariatur laboris excepteur amet Lorem Lorem commodo consequat ullamco. Pariatur aute ut aliqua aliquip consectetur ea.

</body>
```

And CSS:

```
:root[class*=voxel-theme-empresas], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-])
{
  --ids_color_action_primary_base: #ec7000;
  --ids_color_darktBg_base: #001e4f;
  --ids_color_lightBg_base: #fde9d7;
}

:root[class*=voxel-theme-ion], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-])
{
  --ids_color_action_primary_base: #a7ce2e;
  --ids_color_darktBg_base: #133134;
  --ids_color_lightBg_base: #efface;
}

:root[class*=voxel-theme-iti], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-])
{
  --ids_color_action_primary_base: #fe3386;
  --ids_color_darktBg_base: #2b374a;
  --ids_color_lightBg_base: #fcefef;
}

body
{
  font-size: large;
}

h1
{
  color: var(--ids_color_action_primary_base);
}

.vscode-light
{
  background-color: var(--ids_color_lightBg_base);
  color: var(--ids_color_darktBg_base);
}

.vscode-dark
{
  background-color: var(--ids_color_darktBg_base);
  color: var(--ids_color_lightBg_base);
}
```

#### Important observation

The `root` element classes have to remain preserved. I know it will not work if you try to add the class `voxel-theme-empresas` to `body` or `div` because it will trigger `voxel-theme-iti`'s colour instead.

Comment: Not so common knowledge, but you can simply toggle a `<style>` element *enabled/disabled* with  Javascript. Create a `<style id="theme-N">...</style>` for each theme and use a oneliner like `function toggleStyle(e) { e.disabled = !e.disabled; }` with `toggleStyle(document.getElementById('theme-N'))` to toggle between styles. Obviously using a unique `id` for each theme. Here's some [codepen code](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/zYPKEVL?editors=1000) I posted a few months ago doing just that (and then some more). Not for the faint hearted...

Comment: It is a very interesting code. The problem is that, if I use only the pure HTML, the element will trigger only the last `style` even if with a class or an identifier or an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple solution to switch between themes.

```js
// Initial elements
const select = document.getElementById('theme-select');
const button = document.getElementById('dark-mode');
const body = document.body;

const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

const LIGHT = 'vscode-light';
const DARK = 'vscode-dark';

// Selection handler
select.addEventListener('change', event => {
  // We take a second class to use it later
  const classVScode = body.className.split(' ')[1];

  h1.textContent = event.target.value;
  // If the body has no current value (class)
  if (!body.classList.contains(event.target.value)) {
    // Making new styles
    body.className = `${event.target.value} ${classVScode}`;
  }
});

// Switch handler
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // We take a first class to use it later
  const classVoxel = body.className.split(' ')[0];
  // If body has a 'vscode-dark' class
  if (body.classList.contains(DARK)) {
    // Making new styles
    body.className = `${classVoxel} ${LIGHT}`;
    // Set attribute 'data' with theme
    body.setAttribute('data-vscode-theme-kind', `${LIGHT}`);
  } else {
    body.className = `${classVoxel} ${DARK}`;
    body.setAttribute('data-vscode-theme-kind', `${DARK}`);
  }
});
```

```css
.voxel-theme-empresas,
:root:not([class^='voxel-theme-']) {
  --ids_color_action_primary_base: #ec7000;
  --ids_color_darktBg_base: #001e4f;
  --ids_color_lightBg_base: #fde9d7;
}

.voxel-theme-ion,
:root:not([class^='voxel-theme-']) {
  --ids_color_action_primary_base: #a7ce2e;
  --ids_color_darktBg_base: #133134;
  --ids_color_lightBg_base: #efface;
}

.voxel-theme-iti,
:root:not([class^='voxel-theme-']) {
  --ids_color_action_primary_base: #fe3386;
  --ids_color_darktBg_base: #2b374a;
  --ids_color_lightBg_base: #fcefef;
}

body {
  font-size: large;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--ids_color_action_primary_base);
}

.vscode-light {
  background-color: var(--ids_color_lightBg_base);
  color: var(--ids_color_darktBg_base);
}

.vscode-dark {
  background-color: var(--ids_color_darktBg_base);
  color: var(--ids_color_lightBg_base);
}
```

```html
<body class="voxel-theme-empresas vscode-dark" data-vscode-theme-kind="vscode-dark">
  <p>Choose one theme</p>
  <h1>voxel-theme-empresas</h1>
  <select name="theme-select" id="theme-select">
    <option value="voxel-theme-empresas">empresas</option>
    <option value="voxel-theme-ion">ion</option>
    <option value="voxel-theme-iti">iti</option>
  </select>

  <button id="dark-mode">Toggle dark or light mode</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain why `body` still triggered `voxel-theme-iti` even if I selected `voxel-theme-empresas`? It seems to be a problem of `:root`, right?

Comment: @GustavoReis Yes, you are right. It's doesn't trigger because you are trying to add a `pseudo-class` **:root** to a regular class. Yes, **:not()** is also a `pseudo-class`, but for **:not()** to work you put an argument in it, and that's the difference. I fixed and updated the snippet.

Comment: I also need to add `vscode-light` to `body`'s `data-vscode-theme-kind`, replacing `vscode-dark`. Because my VSCode theme is dark, but when I toggled to light mode, the background is still dark. Is it possible? In reference to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154400#event-6973700699.

Comment: I updated the snippet and added a `data-vscode-theme-kind` toggle to the body.